# Help with Engineering Mathematics, Struggling to determine coefficients using methods detailed in this research paper

Tags: electrical-engineering, modeling, mathematics, systems-engineering, systems-design

I am struggling with a curve fitting calculation below. the part I am stuck with is arguably the simplest part, which is determining the coefficients $\\K_3$ and $\\K_4$. It seems like it should be simple/straightforward but it's not clear cut at this stage. some clarity would be appreciated on what I am missing in terms of defining the coefficients of the equation assuming that $\\p = 5$ just to keep it simple.

[image: Formulation for calculating saturation curve part 1]

I am trying to calculate $\\I_s$ using equation **(II.10)** assuming that $\\I_h$ = 0 and $\\I_s = I_0$

if $\lambda\ = \lambda\ _m $  $\sin(\omega t)$

$\lambda\ ^5\ = \lambda\ _m^{5} $  $\sin^{5}(\omega t)$

using the trigonometric power formula:

[image: Trigonometric power formula]

$\lambda\ ^5\ = \lambda\ _m^{5} $  $\sin^{5}(\omega t)$ = 
$\dfrac{1}{16}(10\lambda_m^{5}sin^5(\omega t)-5\lambda_m^{5}sin(3wt)+\lambda_m^{5}sin(5wt))$

[image]

*note: I used wolfram alpha to complete this formula and couldn't figure out how to use subscript, for this equation* $\lambda\ = \lambda\ _m $

I could use some help with determining the coefficients $\\K_3$ and $\\K_4$
what am I missing ?

[image: Formulation for calculating saturation curve part 2]

Comment: You can simplify the problem by noting that $\sin\omega t = \text{Im}[\exp(j\omega t)]$. To find $K_3$ and $K_4$ you need two equations that have to determined from one.  You can do that by equating powers of $\lambda_m$ after computing the RMS value of $i_s$.

Comment: Thank you for this @Biswajit, so in the case of the function $\lambda\ ^5\ = \lambda\ _m^{5} $  $\sin^{5}(\omega t)$ would be simplified to $\frac{j}{32}\lambda _m^{5}\ (exp(jwt) - exp(jwt))^{5}$ and to be clear, finding $\ K_4$ and $\ K_5$ would need a simultaneous equation/system of equations and that could be created by calculating the RMS $\ i_s$ using the expansion for $\lambda$ that I've just done? and use Euler's representation to simplify the calculations ?

Comment: correction, the above expression should be $\frac{j}{32}\lambda _m^{5}\ (exp(jwt) - exp(-jwt))^{5}$

Comment: If $\lambda = \lambda_m \exp(j\omega t)$ then $\lambda^5 = \lambda_m^5 \exp(5j\omega t)$. You can extract the imaginary part after all the calculations have been completed with the exponential form.

Comment: Silly me, we're saying similar things, so effectively what I need to do is find the RMS of the following expression $\ i_s = A_1\lambda + A_5\lambda^{5} = A_1(\lambda_m\exp(j\omega t))+A_5(\lambda_m^{5}exp(5j\omega t))$ and then solve the simultaneous equation of $\ i_{s(RMS)}$ and $\ I_s $ ?

Comment: Yes. The RMS value of $i_s$ does not have $K_3$ and $K_4$, so you will need to compare powers of the $\lambda$s between the two expressions.